# Angular reactive form IP address validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Hellow, i'm try to use a validator for an IP address in angular. However, it seems that even if i inputted an invalid ip address i.e `12.2.2.2...`, GUI shows it is valid (see pic). however, console logs shows that it is a pattern mistmatch (this means that it detected an incorrect pattern). I am not sure what i am missing. starting to get confused now. Need a new pair of eyes to spot the defect.

Please note that the required part is already working with `ipaddress`. I am just confused as to whay it isn't working on pattern validation. See image

[image]

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular-gkhyrw)

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group row required" [ngClass]="{
  'is-invalid': ipaddress.invalid && (ipaddress.dirty || ipaddress.touched),
  'is-valid': ipaddress.valid && (ipaddress.dirty || ipaddress.touched)
}">
  <label for="ipaddress" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">IP Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="IP Address"
        id="ipaddress" name="ipaddress" formControlName="ipaddress"
        ngbAutofocus required>
    <div class="form-control-feedback invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="ipaddress.errors">
      <p *ngIf="ipaddress.errors.required">IP Address is required</p>
      <p *ngIf="ipaddress.errors.pattern">Invalid IP Address format</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS File**

```
  this.ipaddress = new FormControl('', {
      validators: Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)')
      ])
    });
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Instead of creating your own regex, I would go with a custom validator that uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ip

Comment: @Chellappanவ added my stackblitz

Comment: was expecting that when invalid ip address, the input field should be red and not with a checkmark, currenlty, its display green with checkmark on input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have such kind of inconsistency because you're mixing two types of validations that [Bootstrap understands](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation):

**Client-side validation:**

- requires `was-validated` class on the `<form>` tag.

**Server-side validation:**

- no need for `was-validated` class on the  tag.
- requires `.is-valid` or `.is-invalid` class on the input control.

You have `required` attribute on your IP Address input control. This attribute allows browser to apply native built-in form validation, meaning if that control is invalid then it matches the `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class.
Bootstrap framework has dedicated class for this behavior:

```
.was-validated .form-control:invalid {
  border-color: <red>;
  ...
```

Since you're also adding `was-validated` class to the `<form>` tag it works as you expected.

On the other hand you use Angular validation for pattern:

```
this.ipaddress = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern("....")
]);
```

It won't apply buil-in browser validation and you have to set `.is-valid` or `.is-invalid` manually. But **you can use only one type of validation for Bootstrap**.

So, here are your options:

1. Go with client-side validation only:

**html**

```
<input type="ipaddress"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="ipaddress"
    required
    pattern="^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$">
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular-he4n6q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fothers%2Fother.component.html)**

2. Use Bootstrap server-side validation logic.

To do so

- you need to remove adding `was-validated` class to `form` tag but rather set all current control as touched.

e.g.

```
this.myform.markAllAsTouched();
```

- move adding `.is-valid` and `.is-invalid` classes to control itself not to its wrapper

**html**

```
<input type="ipaddress"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="ipaddress"
    [ngClass]="{
  'is-invalid': ipaddress.invalid && (ipaddress.dirty || ipaddress.touched),
  'is-valid': ipaddress.valid && (ipaddress.dirty || ipaddress.touched)
}">
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bs-stepper-angular-md3m6m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fothers%2Fother.component.html)**

Comment: ohh i will just confirm, the angular validator part needs the `pattern` attribute? or basically relies on attributes? it does make sense to me though that i am mixing validations (client to server side) thanks for clearing things up

Comment: Angular has built-in PatternValidator directive https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4481bebb38bdc93f2214f354deee7c5a174e05cf/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L545 It means you can either apply validator in code or by using attribute

Answer (score 2):

For js & ts you can use the following:

```
Validators.pattern('(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)')
```